# Can't increase variable from inside actionlistener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm new to Java and just learning I want to increase a variable by clicking a button but I'm getting the following error

```
local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final
 
The assigned value is never used
```

Adding final doesn't solved the problem and I'm a bit stuck why this doesn't work? can you help?

```
public class JavaApplication2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Click");
 
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
 
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(button);

        int x;
        x = 0;

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("You CLicked the Button " + x + " times");  
                x = x + 1; // *getting error*
            }
        });
 
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setLocation(50,50);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Think of this: the action listener will only ever be called long after the main method has finished running. The local variable `x` will no longer be around at that time.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `X` needs to be *a global, static variable* because you never know when the registered `ActionListener` will be triggered.
`X` is not in that scope and might be already removed at that time.

Comment: Thanks so much! Works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest using something like the following.

You shouldn't use global static variables for such a problem.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JavaApplication2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Click");

        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(button);

        Counter c = new Counter();

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("You CLicked the Button " + c.getValue() + " times");
                c.increment();
            }
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocation(50, 50);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}

class Counter {
    private int value = 0;

    void increment() {
        value++;
    }

    void reset() {
        value = 0;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```